# How to route between subnets

Tags: routing, subnet

Experienced, but very limited network knowledge - please bear with me.

I have a simple PPTP VPN server on my Ubuntu 18.04 server PC (yes, I know it's insecure, etc.). The router, PPTP server and VPN clients all live on the same subnet 192.168.1.x and all works well. I do a little NAT to the server from the router.

My goal is to specify a different subnet for the clients - say 192.168.0.250-252.

Try as I have, no luck. Obviously, there is routing involved which I have no knowledge of. Please, can someone tell me what to do? I would also like, if possible, for the solution to be at the server end, rather than at the client.

This is my current setup:

`192.168.1.1`   Router

`192.168 1.100` PPTP server on enp1s0:

`192.168.1.250-252` VPN clients on ppp0:

What I am looking for is

`192.168.1.1`   Router

`192.168 1.100` PPTP server on enp1s0:

`192.168.0.250-252` VPN clients on ppp0:

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a option of PPT VPN to push route dynamically. If there is, You can write script an push route dynamically , 
In **openvpn** (free) there is this option via

`--client-connect you_script`